# strange iphone os4.0 error while quitting application

Tags: iphone, ios4

I have updated to xcode 3.2.3 iphone os sdk 4.0. now when application enters in background state and when i double tap home screen to quit the bg running app. I receive Kill in gdb.
Does some one knows about it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your quit app app it's no longer running, so GDB get KILL signal, nothing wrong..

Comment: Thanks Nyxem. Now i got another problem I have Added "UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend" key into the info.plist but the app doesn't exit do you know how to quit app when user presses home button in iOS 4.0 ?